# Using OAuth2 in Blazor and redirect user based on claims to certain page after successfull login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

I use [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) (OAuth2/Open ID Connect) to authorize and authenticate users in a Blazor Server Side application. Furthermore I use the `services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect()` extension from Microsoft.

After successfull login I want to redirect the user to a certain page based on its claims. So f.e. if the user has the claim "gis" he should be redirected to "/gis" or if he has the claim "claim123" he should be redirected to page "/page456".

Right now I solve this problem by overriding `OnInitialized` in the `MainLayout.razor` and look if the user has a certain claim and then redirect him with the help of the `NavigationManager`.

```
@inject NavigationManager navMan;
//...
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    if (_user.HasClaim(t => t.Type == "claim123"))
    {
        navMan.NavigateTo("/page456");
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is, that it will first load the default index home page ( "/" ) and then after a short period of time will reload to the new destination. This "flickering" is not very nice and I thought there must be a better way to directly redirect after successful "/openid-connect" redirection. Can I may use some kind of middleware or one of the `OpenIdConnectEvents`?

Comment: I have not used OpenIDConnect but there should be for sure some options that you can set. I have yet to encounter a OAuth portal that does not have URL redirection.

Comment: Well I can set the "redirect url" which redirects to the "/signin-oidc" endpoint but what I am searching is more something like a "return url" which happens after the login magic happening in "/signin-oidc". I could rewrite the entire login extension from micsoroft but I hoped that there is an easier way.